# Vscode - Vagrant not working on integrated terminal

Tags: vagrant, visual-studio-code

I get this when I try to run vagrant from the integrated terminal:

```
$vagrant -v

/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem 
vagrant (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /usr/bin/vagrant:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I made it work!

Honestly I don't know what's the logic behind it, but here it is:

I found this thread with a similar issue: https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/318

So, I went to the `/usr/bin/vagrant` file, the file mentioned in the error:

```
`/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem 
vagrant (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /usr/bin/vagrant:22:in `<main>'`
```

I aded this two lines before loading the `vagrant` gem:

```
ENV.delete("GEM_HOME")
ENV.delete("GEM_PATH")

load Gem.bin_path('vagrant', 'vagrant', version)
```

And now is working like a charm

Comment: I'm using Debian stretch and it did work with adding the suggested 2 lines.